# How to report the result of an olap4j query?

Tags: reporting, olap4j

I wan't to create report from the result of an olap Query, the result type is a cellSet. Does any one have any idea.

thx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to print out results is by using one of the built-in formatter. There is an example [available here](https://code.google.com/p/olap4j-demo/source/browse/trunk/src/org/devdonkey/olap4j/demo/QueryDemo.java).

To programmatically iterate over the axis and positions of a CellSet, you need to iterate over each axis, then each position on the axis. A simple CellSet with two axis (with ordinals known in advance) can be iterated over like so:

```
// Iteration over a two-axis query
for (
  Position axis_0 
  : data.getAxes().get( Axis.ROWS.axisOrdinal() ).getPositions()) 
{
  for (
    Position axis_1
    : data.getAxes().get(Axis.COLUMNS.axisOrdinal()).getPositions())
  {
    Object value =
      data.getCell(axis_0, axis_1)
        .getValue();
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no prob in printing results, my goal is to generate reports with charts ... from the result of the query by using a reporting framework like DynamicReports but the report builder does not support CellSet as an input.

Comment: I had to flip axis_1 and axis_0 in the above fragment.